# AngularJS : ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application

I'm currently developing a SPA application using angularjs and MVC Web Api. I'm trying to fill a grid by fetching data from SQL Server binding it to a datatable and then passing:

```
{ 
  "countryID":null,
  "countryCode":null,
  "countryName":null,
  "currencyCode":null,
  "currencyName":null,
  "currencyDecimals":null,
  "timeZone":null,
  "countries":[],
  "returnStatus":true,
  "returnMessage":["success"],
  "validationErrors":{},
  "totalPages":0,
  "totalRows":0
  "isAuthenicated":false,
  "sortExpression":0,
  "sortDirection":3,
  "currentPageNumber":0,
  "totalPageCount":0,
  "dtMain": [
    {"countryID":1},
    {"countryID":2},
    {"countryID":3},
    {"countryID":4},
    {"countryID":5},
    {"countryID":7} ]
}
```

I'm able to access all the other property but not **dtMain**. My HTML is As Below:

```
<pre>
  <div class="section-box" ng-controller="countryGridController as vm" 
    ng-init="vm.initializeController()"> 
      {{vm.sortDirection}}
      <div data-ng-repeat="obj in vm.dtMain">
          {{obj.countryID}}
      </div>
  </div>
</pre>
```

Comment: You can't access it because countryID is not a propertie of the main object. It is a property of dtMain. I'm going to prepare something to explain it to you.

Comment: Hi Rodmentou were you able to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

$scope variable is used to bind between a view and it's controller, so whatever the object you want to reference from the controller,assign it to a member of $scope in the controller function

```
    function countryGridController(){
        $scope.vm= { 
            "countryID":null,
            "countryCode":null,
            "countryName":null,
            "currencyCode":null,
            //and so on
        };
    }
```

and in the view

```
 <pre>
  <div class="section-box" ng-controller="countryGridController"> 
      {{vm.sortDirection}}
      <div data-ng-repeat="obj in vm.dtMain">
          {{obj.countryID}}
      </div>
  </div>
</pre>
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I didn't understood your reply. Actually i am new to angularjs  . So can you kindly elaborate your explanation

Comment: Hi everyone i resolved the issue. The issue occured as i was not binding the JSON response.dtMain to my vm.dtMain. After doing so i was able to access all the element.